# Edit "Limited Access" Permissions?

Tags: permissions

Is there any way to edit the permissions for "Limited Access" permission level?  It has too many permissions granted.

I understand the official answer is "No," but has anybody tried?  The Roles table, PermMask field controls this, but naturally, I don't like to edit SharePoint tables.  Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Limited Access is no permission per-se - it cannot/should NOT be used by any user, administrator directly! It is SharePoint's doing and it does not give necessarly permisisons to user, beyond what already has, but rather complements existing given permissions with minimum needed so that targeted user could access necessary site section (document, page, list item, List/Library, etc.) to which its been given access.

So you cannot say that "Limited accesss has too many permissions" because that doesn't exist. However, you need to look (via Check permissions, at List item level, or list level or site level - linked to the context you are checking) at whether that user has not been given manually too many permissions.

Remove the user from the site collection altoghether and add him/her again, if you suspect its out of control.

Also, i recomand you rather use Groups to grant access, avoid giving them direct permissions by breaking inheritance - it soon becomes the nightmare of every site admin.

Comment: You cannot explicitly assign it, but Limited Access is a permission level just like any other.  When SharePoint sets a user to Limited Access, they gain the default permissions of Limited Access.

For example, when a user is set to Limited Access by SharePoint, they are GRANTED "Use Remote Interfaces", even though we disabled this for all editable permission levels.  Do you understand the issue?